# How can I arrange more divs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I arrange multiple divs?

You can view as I tried to arrange them:

[image]

I would like the arrangement to be symmetrical, but I don't know how to do that. Because a div could have more text, respectively what would you recommend me to do?

I would like the result to look like this:
[image]

HTML code:

```css
.label {
  width: 3.025in;
  padding: .125in .3in 0;
  margin-right: .125in;
  margin-bottom: .125in;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: 1px dotted;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-8">
        <h3>Books</h3>
        <div class="label">
            <a href="/Books/Details/1"><img src="img.jpg" height="100" width="100"></a>
            <br /> <strong>Title : Test</strong>
            <br /> Author : <strong>Name</strong>
            <br /> Category : <strong>Fantasy</strong>
            <br /> Description: <strong>Description..<a href="/Books/Details/1">Details</a></strong>
            <br /> Price : <strong>1552</strong>
            <br />
            <a class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
            <a class="btn btn-info">Details</a>
            <a class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <h3>Categories</h3>
        <table class="table table-condensed">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href="/Categories/Details/1">Crime</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap? If so, please add the tag. Do you want a Bootstrap solution, or just CSS? Imo you shouldn't mix both for general layout purposes.

Comment: _“I would like the result to look like this:”_ - so you want the items that are displayed on one line next to each other, have the same height, regardless of whether one has content that is shorter than the other? Then go research “equal height columns” in combination with Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example it could be that the div elements have different heights.
I would recommend to

1. use css ellipsis https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow
2. Use a masonry grid https://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 0):

How about using the flex-wrap property of the Flexible Box Layout module. Items that won't fit a parent flex container are forced onto another line.

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="red">1</div>
  <div class="green">2</div>
  <div class="blue">3</div>
  <div class="yellow">4</div>
</div>

/* Flexbox Styles */
.content {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

This gives a nice symmetrical arrangement even if you have an odd number of items in the parent container